# Eclipse Application to standalone?

Tags: java, eclipse, launch

I have been using Eclipse for my Java needs for quite some time now, but I have never really delved deep into it.

I was recently given this project by a friend which makes use of the XText plugin library to act as an IDE for a custom file type.

However, to launch it, I need to open the source of the editor itself in Eclipse and run it as an Eclipse Application which in turns open a separate Eclipse IDE.

I have been looking around for an easy way around this, but to no avail. Is there a way to run said Eclipse Application **without having to first open the source of the custom editor and launching it**?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to build an installable plugin from the project which you can install in to Eclipse. Or build a separate RCP to make a standalone application.

Comment: There is a maven plugin with which you can create installable plugins. Have a look at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Comment: have a look at "eclipse rcp"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a shortcut for Eclipse and adding -data "PATH_TO_APP" on the 'target' field.

Thank you for your help everyone. :)